# React-redux null values are stored as a string

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I have a redux store in my react-project.
The variables in the redux state like the user are subscribed to localStorage items to prevent resetting of values.

My store:

```py
const pixStore = createStore(
combinedReducers, /* preloadedState, */
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

pixStore.subscribe(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('token', pixStore.getState().token);
  localStorage.setItem('user', pixStore.getState().user);
});
```

reducers:

```py
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {UserReducer, tokenReducer} from './authReducers';

// combine all reducers here
const combinedReducers = combineReducers({
    user: UserReducer,
    token: tokenReducer,
})

export default combinedReducers;
```

So when an action is dispatched, I want to set some values of the redux state to `null`. this is how am doing it now.

```py
const tokenReducer = (state=localStorage.getItem('token'), action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        default:
            return state;
        case "REFRESH_TOKEN":
            /* Set token if not exists or update the existing token */
            return state = action.payload;
        case "CLEAR_TOKEN":
            return state = null;
    }
}
```

when I do this, the localStorage item's value is set to `null`
but the state variable's value becomes `"null"`
like it's a string. Because of this my functions don't detect the state variable to be null and it causes a lot of issues.

Why is this happening? Anyway I can fix it? please help me, thanks!!
[image]

Comment: have you checked the type of pixStore.getState().token and ixStore.getState().user? If those a fetch result then maybe its already a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `JSON.parse` method here, LocalStorage.getItem will always give stringified value so `null` become `'null'` to get the real data need to use JSON.parse.

```
state=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'))
```

so our reducer should be like this

```
const tokenReducer = (state=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')), action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        default:
            return state;
        case "REFRESH_TOKEN":
            /* Set token if not exists or update the existing token */
            return state = action.payload;
        case "CLEAR_TOKEN":
            return state = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, it works and now I have a better understanding of JSON.parse
I can accept answer only after 10 min though ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64999492/react-redux-having-trouble-storing-and-retrieving-json-stringified-objects
this is the other question

Comment: can u pls help me with it?