# How to store and retrieve objects in react-redux? [Objects subscribed to local-storage]

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a reducer like this:

```py
const UserReducer = (state=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')), action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        default:
            return state;
        case "REFRESH_AUTH":
            return state = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(action.payload.user));
        case "CLEAR_AUTH":
            return state = null;

    }
}
```

I need to store an object here, and hence I need to stringify it before saving it.
Now, though, when I reload the page and the reducer tries to get

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
```

I get this error:

```py
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at user (authReducers.js:7)
    at redux.js:367
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at redux.js:365
    at s (redux.js:430)
    at Module.79 (index.js:5)
    at a ((index):1)
    at t ((index):1)
    at Array.r [as push] ((index):1)
```

how Can I resolve this, and also,
what's the correct way to store and retrieve objects with redux?

Basically, here's what I want to do:
store the user object as JSON.stringified version to localStorage and then access it through the reducer [JSON.parse] it

Comment: It would help if you know what is stored in localstorage: `console.log(localStorage.getItem('user')
)` Your reducer just needs to return the new state the `state = ` part you can leave out.

Comment: yes I can do that, the problem is with updating the user. How can I do that

Comment: I want to make it such that the localStorage stores stringified version of user
and the reducer returns parsed version of it

Comment: at the starting, the user is null at localStorage. but after that, when the action is dispatched, its an object

Comment: @PsychicSimp based on error stack trace I believe an error in authReducer and not from UserReducer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so, the solution to storing objects and backing them up [subscribing them to] localStorage was this.

I store and return the stringified version of the object from the state.
And then when I want to retieve it, like in a react- component, I just JSON.parse it.

It avoids all the hazzles you have to go through and seems to be the only way, because redux and localStorage cannot actually store **objects**, just strings.

Here's the code:

```py
const UserReducer = (state=localStorage.getItem('user'), action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        default:
            return state;
        case "REFRESH_AUTH":
            return state = JSON.stringify(action.payload.user);
        case "CLEAR_AUTH":
            return state = null;

    }
}
```

Retrieving the object state variable:

```py
function UserArea() {
    const user = JSON.parse(useSelector(state => state.user));
    const full_name = user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name;

    function logoutUser() {
        axios.post('/api/logout/')
            .then(() => {
                <Redirect to='/login/' />
            })
            .catch(error => {console.log(error)});

    }

    return (
        <div className="user-area">
            <div className="button-container">
                <button> <SettingsIcon fontSize="inherit"/> </button>
                <button onClick={logoutUser}>
                <ExitToAppIcon fontSize="inherit"/> </button>
            </div>

            <div className="user-container">
                <div>
                    <h2>{truncate(user.username, 13)}</h2>
                    <h3>{truncate(full_name, 15)}</h3>
                </div>
                <img src={user.avatar_url} className={user.has_premium ? "premiumAvatarIcon" : "defaultAvatarIcon"}></img>
            </div>

        </div>
    );

}
```